# Pointing to a const pointer (or a pointer to a const)

Tags: c++, pointers

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){

    int v1 = 20;

    int *p1 = &v1;
    int **p2 = &p1;

    return 0;
}
```

What I want to do here is pointing a pointer to another pointer, and it works fine in this case.

I make p1 to a `const` pointer OR a pointer to a `const`:

```
int *const p1 = &v1; OR
const int *p1 = &v1;
```

Now my code does not work.
Considering the first case. `int *const p1 = &v1;`.
Here is my updated code, which I think should be right:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){

    int v1 = 20;

    int *const p1 = &v1;
    const int **p2 = &p1;

    return 0;
}
```

Making the pointer itself `const` means that it cannot point to another object, but the value of that object which it was pointing can be changed. So if I want to point another pointer to the previous pointer `p1`, I need to make sure that this second pointer cannot be used to change the value of `p1` So I make it (`p2`) a pointer to a `const`. But it does not work.

Error: : invalid conversion from 'int* const*' to 'const int**' [-fpermissive]

Similarly, the second case fails too. My code which I think should be right:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){

    int v1 = 20;

    const int *p1 = &v1;
    int **p2 = &p1;

    return 0;
}
```

Making a pointer point to a const means that the pointer cannot be used to change the value of the object which it was pointing to. However, the pointer can change it's own value, that is it can point to other objects. Since I can change the value of the pointer, the second pointer need not to be pointing to a const.

Error: invalid conversion from 'const int**' to 'int**' [-fpermissive]

I am using the GNU CC Compiler 
I am new to C++ and I am lost. I would like to know how to point pointers to other pointer which are involved with `const`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first rewrite did not work, because you tried to assign an address of a constant pointer to a pointer-to-pointer where the final "pointee" (i.e. the `int`) is constant, rather than the pointer in the middle. In other words, if C allowed this

```
int *const p1 = &v1;
const int **p2 = &p1; // Not allowed
```

it should allow this:

```
*p2 = &v2; // This would be legal.
```

However, this would have modified the pointer `p1`, which is allegedly constant.

Here is what you need to change for the first rewrite to work:

```
int *const p1 = &v1;
int * const *p2 = &p1;
```

Note how `const` is moved from before the declaration to between the asterisks. Now you are making a pointer to a constant pointer to int.

Your second rewrite fails because it drops `const`-ness altogether. To fix it, put `const` back at the beginning of the declaration:

```
const int *p1 = &v1;
const int **p2 = &p1;
```

Answer (score 3):

> I would like to know how to point pointers to other pointer which are involved with const.

You need to use `const` in the pointer-to-pointer as well, obviously.

```
int *const p1 = &v1;
int *const* p2 = &p1;


const int *p1 = &v1;
const int **p2 = &p1;
```

The basic rule is very simple, if you have a variable of type `T`, a pointer to it has type `T*`. So if you have `int * const *` then a pointer to it is `int * const **`, not `const int **`, which is a pointer to a different type.

> Since I can change the value of the pointer, the second pointer need not to be pointing to a const.

No, that's incorrect.

If C++ allowed that you could modify const data, or try to anyway:

```
const int v1 = 0;
const int* p1 = &v1;
int** p2 = &p1;
int* p3 = *p2;
*p3 = 1;              // modifies v1, which is const!
```

The point of the rule is to enforce type safety and not allow you to point to const data with a pointer to non-const.

Answer (score 1):

```
int *const p1 = &v1;
```

This statement is saying that p1 is a `"constant pointer to integer"`.

```
const int **p2 = &p1;     //wrong
```

whereas this is saying that p2 is pointer to a `"pointer to constant integer"` which is contradicting your first statement.

So second statement should be ( if first statement is unchanged) :-

```
int* const *p2 = &p1;
```

which would say that p2 is pointer to a `"constant pointer to integer"`.

OR

first statement should be ( if second statement is unchanged) :-

```
const int *p1 = &v1;
```

which would say p1 is a `"pointer to constant integer"`.

Comment: What about `const int *p1` in your last code? Will it be correct?

Comment: This is compatible with your second statement "const int **p2 = &p1"

Answer (score 1):

The thing that helps is writing the `const`'s (or cv-qualifications in general) right-to-left.

```
int const* p1 = &v1;

int const* *p2 = &p1;
```

That's okay.

```
int      * const p1 = &v1;

int const*      *p2 = &p1;
```

That's not okay.

```
int const*  p1 = &v1;
int      * *p2 = &p1;
```

And that's not okay either.

Can you spot the pattern?

Comment: Sorry, but I did not understand a thing.

Comment: @EmpereurAiman I tried to encourage you to think for yourself. You know, learning effect and stuff.

Comment: I would have understood better if you said, "read the `const`'s ...." instead of "write the `const`s" :)
I have understood the post after sometime, thanks